# Is there a way to append text/values to a specific line in R?

Tags: r, input, rscript

I've got an Rscript that is meant to append a specific character string and value to the bottom of a text file:

```
r = read.table('template.txt', header = F) 

a = floor(runif(1, min = 0, max = 500))

write(sprintf('AncestralSize='),
      "/directory/template/template.txt",
      append = T)

write(a, 
      "/directory/template/template.txt",
      append = T)
```

This does append the value to the bottom of template.txt, but like this:

```
AncestralSize=
150
```

This causes an error further down the line in my code, as for the next programme to work, it must be on the same line, like so:

```
AncestralSize=150
```

I tried not appending it direct to the bottom of the file and only using `sep=T` but that just deleted the rest of the template.

I'm not sure how to use `sed` and other C++ commands within this script, or even if it would be appropriate (which I would guess not).

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `write(sprintf("AncestralSize=%i", a), ...)`? The intended use of `sprintf` is to create *"a `character` vector containing a formatted combination of text and variable values"* (where "variable values" is your `a`).

Comment: @r2evans thank you so much, that works!